# shell script to search for a substring on AIX OS

Tags: shell

I need to search the string "-Xms" from the below code:

```
cat | ps -eaf|grep $LOGNAME | while read LINE
do
if [[ grep LINE = "-Xms" ]]; then
         pid=$(echo $LINE | awk '{print $2}')
    #echo $pid
     kill -9 $pid
 fi
 :
done
```

But this code does not work on AIX. It works fine on Linux.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I made small changes in the script like making a variable for storing return of grep.
Try this

```
ps -aef|grep $LOGNAME | while read LINE
do
PAT=`grep "\-Xms" $LINE`
if [ "$PAT" != "" ]; then
     pid=$(echo $LINE | awk '{print $2}')
    #echo $pid
     #kill -9 $pid
fi
done
```

Comment: error grep: 0652-033 Cannot open 0.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open 12:43:30.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open -.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open 0:00.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open -m.

Comment: This code throws the following error:grep: 0652-033 Cannot open 0.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open 12:43:30.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open -.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open 0:00.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open sshd:.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open appuser@notty.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open root.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open 10158276.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open 5636342.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open 0.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open Feb.
etc..===============

Comment: Yes there is a error in my code...Will correct it with right option

Answer (score 0):

i did not test though.
your complete loop can be replaced with :

```
ps -eaf | grep $LOGNAME| grep "-Xms"|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
```

coming to searching for substring:

```
cat | ps -eaf|grep $LOGNAME |grep "-Xms" while read LINE   
do   
pid=$(echo $LINE | awk '{print $2}')       
kill -9 $pid
done
```